# Interface declaration together with generic constraints

Tags: c#, generics

**Basic C# syntax question:**

So I have this class

```
public class BrandQuery<T> : Query<T> where T : Ad
{
  //...
}
```

How do I specify that BrandQuery implements an interface, say IDisposable ?

This is obviously the wrong way:

```
public class BrandQuery<T> : Query<T> where T : Ad, IDisposable
{
  //...
}
```

because that would only put a generic constraint on T.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The generic type constraints follow all the base-class / interfaces:

```
public class BrandQuery<T> : Query<T>, IDisposable
    where T : Ad
{
  //...
}
```